# Three way grouping in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in a pivot table that I need grouped in such a way that I'm not certain is possible.

My data is formatted in such a way

```
No.             Document No.           Jan    Feb  Mar Apr May June July
123456        S1                      1      0    2   0    0    
              S2                       0     1         2     
              S3
789           S4                          etc
123           S2
```

What I want to happen: Group the report in such a way that puts the #s in a "bucket" based on if they have ever occurred together in the Document # in any instance.

If I move the pivot table such that Document # is first, it just puts in the #s that occurred for that one document #. There are 10,000+ document #s, 600~ item #s.

I attempted V-LOOKUP on Document No. to pull the No. from, but that only pulls the first instance, not the whole compendium of listed No.'s

I will mention that I have the data not in a pivot table in such a fashion

```
No.           Doc No.            Quantity       Date
123456         S1                   1            1/1/2018
123            S2                   2            1/1/2018
etc            etc                  etc           etc
```

Comment: Can you share the sample expected outcome?

Comment: The sample is not very clearly, could you provide the Table here?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you determine the date to use, nor why No. 789  and Documents 53 and 54 are not listed in your results table.